# Caliburn Micro: ElementName for ComboBox in DataGrid not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, caliburn.micro, elementname

my problem is that the ItemsSource of a ComboBox in an DataGrid is not binding.
My UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyClass"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="360" d:DesignWidth="757">
```

The DataGrid:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="Article" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
              Margin="5">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                                    Header="Article">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredArticle, ElementName=Root}"                                      IsEditable="True" 
                                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action FindArticlel($source)]" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If I don't say ElementName=Root, he tries to bind FilteredArticle in the Article class.
If I say ElementName=Root, he says the following at runtime:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Root'. BindingExpression:Path=FilteredArticle; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

FilteredArticle is a BindableCollection in my ViewModel. All other bindings are working.
What is wrong here?
Using the latest stable version of Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding to the view via `ElementName` is usually a bad practice. Mainly because someone that creates an instance of the view can give it a different `x:Name` and that will break your internal binding.

Plus, the `FilteredArticle` property is not the property of the view but of the view model which is the data context for the view.

Use relative source for binding in those scenarios

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FilteredArticle, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                             AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

You can use a more specific notation (although, in 99% of cases it's not necessary)

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FilteredArticle, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                             AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClass}}}"
```

Where `local` is the `xmlns` for the namespace of `MyClass`